# PHP in_array problems

Tags: php

So I'm trying to upload image and I only want jpg, jpeg and png to be uploaded so I had this file that checks if the image is either jpg, jpeg or png :

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    foreach ($_FILES['img_items'] as $key => $image) {
        var_dump($image);
    }

    $filetype = $_FILES['img_items']['type'];

    $allowed = array("png" => "image/png", "jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg");
    if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){
        echo 'PASSED<br/>';
    }else{
        echo 'FAILED<br/>';
    }

    var_dump($filetype);

}

?>
```

The code above is simplified for testing purposes.
It should gave me the file details then echo "PASSED" if the filetype is jpg, jpeg or png.

When I uploaded a jpg or jpeg image, it works fine with "PASSED" as the result. 
But when I uploaded PNG file, I got "FAILED".. Which does not make sense and I even switched the order of the array so that png is in the front but still the same issue..

I had tested this with 3 diffrent PNG image, taken by diffrent camera/source's.

Here's what it shows me :
https://ibb.co/bVNkGT

The original file was this :

```
# Check for packaging image and process it.
            if(isset($_FILES["img_package"]) && $_FILES["img_package"]["error"] == 0){
                $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "png" => "image/png");
                $filename = $_FILES["img_package"]["name"];
                $filetype = $_FILES["img_package"]["type"];
                $filesize = $_FILES["img_package"]["size"];

                $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)){
                    $_SESSION['errMsg'] = 'Uploaded photo extension is not allowed! Only .jpg, .jpeg and .png is allowed';
                    header("location: /inbound/add");
                };

                $maxsize = 3 * 1024 * 1024;
                if($filesize > $maxsize){
                    $_SESSION['errMsg'] = 'Uploaded photo exceeded 3MB file limit';
                    header("location: /inbound/add");
                };

                if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){

                    $rand = rand(pow(10, 6-1), pow(10, 6)-1);

                    if(file_exists("../images/". $rand . $_FILES["img_package"]["name"])){
                        $_SESSION['errMsg'] =  $rand . $_FILES["img_package"]["name"] . " exsisted!<br/>Try again if the photo is diffrent.";
                        header("location: /inbound/add");
                    }else{
                        # Package Image Mover is moved below so thefile will NOT be moved untill everyhting is cleared.
                    } 
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['errMsg'] = 'Uploaded photo extension is not allowed! Only .jpg, .jpeg and .png are allowed 1';
                    header("location: /inbound/add");
                }
            }else{
                $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "Error: " . $_FILES["img_package"]["error"];
                header("location: /inbound/add");
            }

            # Check for items image and process it.
            if(isset($_FILES['img_items'])){

                # Define variables
                $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "png" => "image/png");
                $maxsize = 3 * 1024 * 1024;

                # Loop the image array
                foreach ($_FILES["img_items"]["error"] as $key => $error){
                    # Check for error
                    if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
                        # Define variable
                        $filename = $_FILES["img_items"]["name"];
                        $filetype = $_FILES["img_items"]["type"];
                        $filesize = $_FILES["img_items"]["size"];
                        # Check if the file extenstion is allowed
                        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)){
                            $_SESSION['errMsg'] = 'Uploaded photo extension is not allowed! Only .jpg, .jpeg and .png is allowed';
                            header("location: /inbound/add");
                        };
                        # Check file size
                        if($filesize > $maxsize){
                            $_SESSION['errMsg'] = 'Uploaded photo exceeded 3MB file limit';
                            header("location: /inbound/add");
                        };
                        # Confirm file is allowed
                        if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){
                            # Randomize prefix to prevent duplicate image error
                            $rand = rand(pow(10, 6-1), pow(10, 6)-1);
                            # Check if the file exsisted
                            if(file_exists("../images/". $rand . $_FILES["img_items"]["name"])){
                                $_SESSION['errMsg'] =  $rand . $_FILES["img_items"]["name"] . " exsisted!<br/>Try again if the photo is diffrent.";
                                header("location: /inbound/add");
                            }else{
                                define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
                                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_items"]["tmp_name"], SITE_ROOT."inferno/inbound/images/" . $rand . $_FILES["img_items"]["name"]);
                                $img_items[] = $rand.$_FILES["img_items"]["name"];
                            } 
                        }else{
                            $_SESSION['errMsg'] = 'Uploaded photo extension is not allowed! Only .jpg, .jpeg and .png are allowed 2';
                            header("location: /inbound/add");
                        } 
                    }else{
                        $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "Error: " . $_FILES["img_items"]["error"];
                        header("location: /inbound/add");
                    }
                }
            }
```

the first one (img_package) works fine but the 2nd one (img_items) returns error when given a PNG file.
Any help is appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is var_dump() showing?

Comment: Any chance the filetype is `"PNG"` instead of `"png"`? Been there, done that, and it's real annoying.

Comment: PNG files can be either `image/png` or `image/x-png`

Comment: @Loek, the file I'm uploading ends with "png" lowercased..

Comment: Then just have it like this `strtolower($filetype)` to avoid those problems

Comment: @Mehdi, https://pastebin.com/CCc4y7E6 still the same problem occured.

Comment: @Dormilich,  https://ibb.co/bVNkGT

Comment: can you change this line `$filetype = $_FILES['img_items']['type'];` to this
`$filetype = $_FILES['img_items']['type'][0];` 

seems like you are uploading multiple image with same name
because `var_dump($filetype);` is printing array rather than string

Comment: you should also give screenshot of your html markup

Comment: @SambhajiKatrajkar, The `in_array($filetype[0], $allowed)` worked and PNG or JPG files are returning "PASSED" right now. But when I'm uploading multiple file's, one is PNG and the other is RAR, it shows https://ibb.co/ePx8mT. The code has been updated to : https://pastebin.com/EXjVZMqE

Comment: @AmitBisht, https://pastebin.com/PWkJqEqK is the form code

Comment: @AmitBisht, yes it is correct that I'm trying to upload multiple image's. I had changed it to `$filetype = $_FILES['img_items']['type'][0];` and now I get this as the result : https://ibb.co/ePx8mT when uploading a png and a rar file.

Comment: simple you can check like this for multiple file upload `if(count(array_diff($filetype,$allowed))){
    
    echo "some of the file not allowed";   
}`

Comment: @JYoThI, that actually works and this changes the way I viewed the file. Now I've changed it to : https://pastebin.com/hT9UZmLD and it works fine. But there's one problem that I've founded.. A RAR or ZIP file will cause the script to crash and shows this : https://ibb.co/g6d9t8 . When it's working, it shows this : https://ibb.co/ncfiLo

Comment: check this `if($_FILES['img_items']['error'] == 0){ echo "file problem"; }`

Comment: @JYoThI, I do check that :) thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the code:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    foreach ($_FILES['img_items'] as $key => $image) {
        var_dump($image);
    }

    $filetype = $_FILES['img_items']['type'];

    $allowed = array("png" => "image/png", "jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg");
    if(in_array($filetype[0], array_values($allowed))){
        echo 'PASSED<br/>';
    }else{
        echo 'FAILED<br/>';
    }

    var_dump($filetype);

}

?>
```

Comment: And then JPG images start to fail because you're searching for values instead of keys.

Comment: in $filetype you will get `images/jpeg`, not only `jpeg`. If you want to check for file extension then use `array_keys()` instead of `array_values()`

Comment: Then I'm really wondering why OP's solution did work with JPG images...

Comment: Check for the value you are getting in $filetype and write condition according to that.

Comment: According to OP: *When I uploaded a jpg or jpeg image, it works fine with "PASSED" as the result. But when I uploaded PNG file, I got "FAILED".* This is weird if what you say is true, since his JPG file should have failed as well. Oh well.

Comment: Please check updated answer. I have added `[0]` to `$filetype` in `in_array`

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm trying to upload multiple image's, the $filetype variable is actually an array which somehow caused an error upon uploading a file that is not JPG or JPEG.

The fix was :

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $filetype = $_FILES['img_items']['type'];
    $allowed = array("png" => "image/png", "jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg");

    foreach ($filetype as $key => $type) {

        var_dump($type);

        if(in_array($type, $allowed)){
            echo 'PASSED<br/>';
        }else{
            echo 'FAILED<br/>';
        }

    }

}

?>
```

Now it is working as expected.
Sorry for the confusion/trouble caused.

Comment: @SambhajiKatrajkar, Yes your solution is also working but it will only check for the first array ("[0]") so the rest is not checked.. Im sorry for not mentioning that this was supposed to be a multiple file upload.

Comment: if you have multiple file upload, then you can use array_intersect() instead of in_array(), but yeah.. your solution will give you correct result

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it like this

```
        $fileType = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        $fileExt = explode('.', $fileType);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

        if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){


                     }
```

Comment: Your code has some errors in it, the $fileName variable is not defined but I've fixed it. I've modified the code to : https://pastebin.com/JSfuXAQn but I get this error : https://ibb.co/js39bT

Comment: that $fileExt will certainly break. A file name can contain more than one "."

Comment: @JasonNathanael Had a typo , try again

Comment: No idea who would downvote this because it is just working normal .. no reason to downvote and otherwise tell me why